# Calling instance methods of function caller in python

Tags: python, plugins

Hi everyone,

I'm trying to create a 'plugin' system using Python (2.7.6). I have a class which implements basic manipulation on a custom hardware board (uses a C++ shared library), and I'd like developers to be able to extend the functionality of this class using some sort of plugin system. For various reasons, all functionality should be available at the same level (say, one class instance), so all function calls, explicitly implemented or imported from plugins, should be callable from the board instance.

Additionally, the functions in these plugins need to use the functions defined in the calling class. For example, a channelisation plugin would need to use the read and write calls implemented in the Board class which imports it. I've started with an abstract base class for the plugins as follows:

```py
class FirmwareBlock(object):
    """ Abstract super class which must be used to implement firmware
        block plugins to be used with the access layer """

    def __init__(self):
        """ Class initialiser """
        # Define class as an abstract class
        __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def initialise(self):
        """ Abstract method where all firmware block initialisation should be performed """
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def status_check(self):
        """ Abstract method where all status checks should be performed """
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def clean_up(self):
        """ Abstract method where all cleaning up should be performed when unloading firmware """
        pass
```

The functions defined in this class must be implemented by all subclasses. In turn, subclasses can implement their own specific functions which must be included in the board class, for example:

```py
class ChanneliserBlock(FirmwareBlock):

    def initialise(self):
        print "ChanneliserBlock has been initialised"
        return True

    def status_check(self):
        print "Checking status"
        return True

    def clean_up(self):
        print "Performed clean_up"
        return True

    def initialise_channeliser(self, *args, **kwargs):
        value = 1
        writeRegister('register1', value)
        if readRegister('register1', value) == value:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

The board (calling) class then should be capable of loading in modules, inspecting custom functions and wrapping them so that they are callable directly from it. This is what I have till now:

```py
def loadPlugin(self, plugin):
    # Check if module is available
    if plugin not in self._availablePlugins:
        print "Module %s is not available" % plugin
        return Error.Failure

    # Get list of class methods and remove those availale in superclass
    methods = [name for name, mtype in
               inspect.getmembers(eval(plugin), predicate=inspect.ismethod)
               if name not in
               [a for a, b in inspect.getmembers(FirmwareBlock, predicate=inspect.ismethod)] ]

    # Create plugin instances
    instance = globals()[plugin]
    self.__dict__[plugin] = instance

    # Import plugins function into this class
    for method in methods:
        # Link class method to function pointer
        self.__dict__[method] = getattr(instance, method)
```

This should allow me to call plugin methods, however the plugins cannot access the functions defined in the board itself. I can, of course, pass the instance of the board to init when instantiating the class, however this tightly couples plugins with the board classes. I was wondering whether there's a better way to do this (fro example, extracting the methods and attaching them directly to the board class, assuming no instance members are being used)